# Get lastInsertId with left padding PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I want to get `lastInsertId()` method output row number 2 as 000002 like that. How should I do it? If it is select statement I can get it with `LPAD()`. But in this case how is it done?

Comment: Either format it in php or do not call pdo wrapper, but select it direclty the way you want - in mysql function return value must be always inserted, pdo only hides this for your convenience. [LAST_INSERT_ID manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: So how should I modified it with PHP

Comment: use str_pad on value returned from lastInsertId()

Comment: Sorry, "return value must be always inserted" - should have been "return value must be always selected" :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're still in the same MySQL session that you have executed the `INSERT` statement in, you can calculate the formatted last inserted id with the following expression:

```
LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), GREATEST(6, LENGTH(LAST_INSERT_ID())), '0')
```

This will return the id value with leading zeros, totalling to 6 digits by default. It also takes into account if the id value is longer than 6 digits (that's what the `GREATEST(...)` does).

You can use that expression for selecting the formatted last id, assign it to a MySQL variable:

```
SELECT LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), GREATEST(6, LENGTH(LAST_INSERT_ID())), '0');
SET @myId = LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), GREATEST(6, LENGTH(LAST_INSERT_ID())), '0');
```

You can also use it in other statements, but note that `LAST_INSERTED_ID()` will change after further `INSERT` statements.

You can also use the last inserted id returned from MySQL in PHP and format it there:

```
$formattedId = sprintf('%06d', lastInsertId());
```

The `sprintf` will extend the id to 6 digits by default, but will also work with longer ids.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get it from mysql query, you may refer to the following statement :

```
SELECT
    LPAD(columnname, length(columnname),'00000')
FROM
    TABLENAME
ORDER BY 
    COLUMNNAME DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: sorry I did not ask about select command with LPAD. I already know it

Comment: you may get it from mysql_insert_id() in php. Also refer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: You may also use str_pad function for adding padding to a particular string.